# How to pull information from website onto my project?

Tags: python, html, module

I have one problem and it's about getting information from website into my python project (while project is running). I haven't coded anything yet since I am beginner in this kind of programming. I would like to ask you which modules i need and how to use them and, if some of you can, I would appreciate some example of a code.

Comment: This site is for specific, focused, answerable, reusable questions, not project planning.

Comment: Who says that this question isn't reusable?

Comment: It isn't a stupid question, we expert exist to help peoples that are totally beginners to enter in correct mindset

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use an API, depending on the website they will usually have api documentation that you can then pull into your project using a python library.

Examples:
API: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Python Library: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the concepts of how to fetch information into a python script or a project through different libraries.
For example - Flask or Django etc.

You can use API documentations for fetching all essentials into your Python project.

For reference you can visit some repos:

https://github.com/VivanVatsa/miiBETA

https://github.com/VivanVatsa/YapMapZ

https://github.com/VivanVatsa/Block-Jack

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are talking about web scraping :

1. you can use BeatifulSoap to extract information from website
2. You have to understand get, request, dump and load functions in python
3. Study HTTP Get requests

In your project your main points must be :

1. Choose the website you want to scrape data
2. Look into robot.txt (it's a file that tells google robot miner if he can extract data or not, just google it)
   3)Once that you know that you can scrape data from website, look at html of page(use firefox with f12) and identify the tags / id

```html
<title id="article"> Free code for everyone</title>
<title id ="article"> Found gold in mines ! </title>
```

you will find yourself with an array like this

```
array_articles =['Free code for everyone','Found gold in mines !']
```

Look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_VZ7NpVw1Y or search on youtube
"how to scrape data from website"